# The JS code fails to execute (or do anything) when I click the submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just learning Javascript, and this is my first attempt to make something for myself, so forgive me if the solution is very simple. I'm trying to automate score keeping for a card game. When I click the submit button, nothing happens.

```
<div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row mt-4 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <img class="img-fluid logo" alt="cards" src="img/cards.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <h1>Shayne's Golf Tally</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center round">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 id="round">Round: 0</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mt-3">
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3 class="names">Shayne</h3>
                <h3 id="shayne">0</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3 class="names">Amber</h3>
                <h3 id="amber">0</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-3 centered input-spacing">
                <input class="form-control input-form" id="inputShayne">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 centered input-spacing">
                <input class="form-control input-form" id="inputAmber">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mt-4">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="tallyScore()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="golf.js"></script>
```

And the javascript:

```
var round = 0;
var scoreShayne = 0;
var scoreAmber = 0;

function tallyScore() {
    round += 1;
    document.getElementById(round).innerHTML = "Round: " + round;
    scoreShayne += document.getElementById("inputShayne").value;
    scoreAmber += document.getElementById("inputAmber").value;
    document.getElementById(shayne).innerHTML = scoreShayne;
    document.getElementById(amber).innerHTML = scoreAmber;
}
```

Comment: The arguments to `.getElementById()` should be quoted strings.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks

Comment: Also don't forget that `value` is a string, and thus you need to use `+` or `parseInt`, like this: `scoreShayne += +document.getElementById("inputShayne").value;` (note `+` before `document.`). Otherwise your scores are not summed up (1+1+1=3), but concatenated ("1"+"1"+"1"="111").

Comment: Hello, JVX, welcome to SO. Try to make the title more specific and descriptive so it can help other people.  Also, if the console shows any error, add this info to the question.

Comment: Thank you, @alx! I figured that out early on. I was able to find that I could use .valueAsNumber instead of .value, which worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some recommandations in this code, just to see ;)

```js
// global values
var round       = 0
,   scoreShayne = 0
,   scoreAmber  = 0
;

// use constants to prevent the JS interpreter from recalculating each call
const hmi_round       = document.getElementById('round')
,     hmi_shayne      = document.getElementById('shayne')
,     hmi_amber       = document.getElementById('amber')
,     hmi_inputShayne = document.getElementById('inputShayne')
,     hmi_inputAmber  = document.getElementById('inputAmber')
;

function tallyScore()
{
  hmi_round.textContent = "Round: " + ++round;  //  ++round is a direct increment (different from round++ )

  hmi_shayne.textContent = scoreShayne += hmi_inputShayne.valueAsNumber; // HTML5 as valueAsNumber
  hmi_amber.textContent  = scoreAmber  += hmi_inputAmber.valueAsNumber;  // instead of parseInt(hmi_inputAmber.value)

  hmi_inputShayne.value = "0";  // reset values for the next round
  hmi_inputAmber.value  = "0";
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-content">
  <div class="row mt-4 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <img class="img-fluid logo" alt="cards" src="img/cards.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h1>Shayne's Golf Tally</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center round">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 id="round">Round: 0</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mt-3">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3 class="names">Shayne</h3>
      <h3 id="shayne">0</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3 class="names">Amber</h3>
      <h3 id="amber">0</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3 centered input-spacing">
      <input class="form-control input-form" id="inputShayne" type="number"min="0" value="0">   <!-- don't forget to set the type -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 centered input-spacing">
      <input class="form-control input-form" id="inputAmber" type="number" min="0" value="0">  <!-- don't forget to set the type -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mt-4">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="tallyScore()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra input! Having someone give suggestions on my code past the initial question is huge for me. I appreciate it.